# Text is not displaying in textview and button in android studio & device also, how to resolve it?

Tags: android

Everything was working fine but suddenly it stopped displaying text from every textviews and buttons from layouts which I created.

I tried running the project in device, invalidated & restarted the android studio, clean the project, rebuild the project even I tried using the code in another computer but nothing worked to solve it.

text is not displaying for textview: [Splash Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbjAE.png)

text is not displaying for two textviews and one button: [Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by0GH.png)

Comment: add your xml layout code.

Comment: **Do not add code as images!** Copy-paste the text into the question. See [the formatting guide](/help/formatting) for help to properly add the code to the question.

Comment: Well the issue is resolved as it was due to my silly mistake of refactoring & yes noted won’t add code as images next time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you want to show must be given in `android:text`. When in doubt, it's always worth refering to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:text).
So, for you would need to do something along the following lines.

```
<TextView 
android:text = "Welcome to my DigiCab"
.../>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I might have refactored the text with title which lead to this.

Comment: No probs, we all make mistakes sooner or later, do click on the Tick mark if it got resolved. :)